# How to Serialize and Deserialize PageElement objects

Tags: javascript, google-slides-api

I am trying to save a Shape object using Google Slides API and then restore the shape to insert it into a different slide or presentation. As far as I could see, the shape is handled as a PageElement object.

Is there any convenient way to serialize the PageElement objects in the new Google Slides API, as a serialized text or JSON format? And then reverse back this serialization to insert the object again into the slide?

*P.S. Maybe regenerating the object from the objectId or any other way using element.asShape(). For the purpose of exploring the new Google Slides API, I tried to modify [the Translate Add-on sample](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/slides/samples/translate).*

*I also found useful the documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/slides/selecting) but unfortunately it didn't answer my question.*

Comment: Don't think there's a straightforward solution to this. This will have to rely on your implementation. What have you tried?

Comment: @noogui - Since I could not get the object serialized, what I tried was to get the object representation via HTTP and using OAuth2 (I used the playground for this). Here is an example of response I got after requesting the pageElements for one of the slides: https://pastebin.com/xGiisJFx